# iOS membership renewal few days late

Tags: ios, membership, renewal

What happens if I renew my iOS membership few days late? I know that Apple will deny "my ability to distribute applications on the App Store and your access to the iPhone Developer Program Portal." and that all my existing certificates and provisioning profiles will be revoked and invalidated. BUT, what will happen if I renew few days after that? I did not get any emails from Apple about renewal and I just found out that today is the last day to renew. Since I am from Croatia I can not pay with my credit card online, I have to send a fax. I don't think that Apple will send me a renewal code immediately and I just want to know what will happen when I renew it? Will I still have my existing apps? Will I lose anything? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

To answer my own question. I renewed my iOS membership one day later than the due date. All my apps were "unavailable for purchase". Customers contacted me with questions why is my app in appstore if it says that it is unavailable for purchase. Everything went to normal the day that my membership was renewed. All my apps were still there and they became available for purchase again. So, it looks that it is not so much of a problem if someone is late a few days with iOS membership renewal.